# GET /admin/webhooks.json returns an empty array

Tags: ruby, shopify, httparty

When doing GET /admin/webhooks.json it simply returns:

```
{"webhooks"=>[]}
```

I've created 8 webhooks using the admin panel but I can't seem to access them using the API. If I enter [https://SHOP_NAME.myshopify.com/admin/webhooks.json](https://%3CSHOP_NAME%3E.myshopify.com/admin/webhooks.json) directly into the browser it does return all the webhooks.

Here's the call I'm making using the credentials from a private app:

```
require 'httparty'

data = HTTParty.get("https://<API_KEY>:<PASSWORD>@<SHOP_NAME>.myshopify.com/admin/webhooks.json", :headers => {'Content-Type' => 'application/json'})
```

Any idea what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The /admin/webhooks.json endpoint only returns the webhooks that you have registered with that API key. That's why I'm seeing an empty array.

Answer (score 0):

Scanning through the [Shopify API authentication](https://docs.shopify.com/api/authentication/oauth) docs doesn't give any indication that [HTTP basic authentication](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2617) of the form `https://<API_KEY>:<PASSWORD>@...` is supported.

This may be the reason why you can't query the hooks. In you browser you may use a web session. You can verify by removing the basic auth from the url and open again in you browser

`https://<SHOP_NAME>.myshopify.com/admin/webhooks.json`

Comment: I'm using private app credentials, https://docs.shopify.com/api/authentication/creating-a-private-app